# Gradle task is broken - cannot execute

Tags: gradle

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens
task genScript(type:Copy){
    copy{
        from "../../scripts/script.txt"
        into projectDir
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [baseName: jar.baseName, version: jar.version, prefix: 'x']
    }
}

jar.doLast{
    tasks.genScript.execute()
}
```

`genScript` executes fine if I just click on it and run. But when I do `..\gradlew clean jar`, it gives me the following error:

> Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task ':myModule:genScript' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.

How to fix it?

I am using Gradle 6.0.1.

Answer (score 6):

You can't programatically execute tasks from other tasks in newer versions of Gradle. Instead, you are supposed to declare task dependencies and Gradle will ensure they get executed in the correct order.

The quick fix is just to make `jar` depend on your task like this:

```
jar.dependsOn('genScript')
```

Alternatively, you could move your logic into the `doLast` block in the `jar` task.